# Select all empty columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, here's a user table

```
Id, Name, Birthdate, Address, Memo
----------------------------------
1,  abc,           
2,  test           , foo,
```

There are some columns, users never filled anything, I want to find out which of the columns that are empty in every row. As in this example, `Birthdate` and `Memo` were never used. So we can call they are empty columns.

Of course I can execute multiple queries:

```
select top 1 from user where Name is not null;
select top 1 from user where Birthdate is not null;
...
```

But it's labourious. Do you have any better way?

Comment: By "empty" do you mean null? So in the first row of your sample data, columns _Birthdate_, _Address_ and _Memo_ are all null?

Comment: @Abra, yes, but single row is not decisive. Only if all rows for a certain column are null is treated as the column is null.

Comment: something like this ? `IF NOT EXISTS (select * from [user] where Name is not null) THEN 'Name is not used' ELSE 'Name is used' END`